# VMWare ESXi 3.5 Wake On Lan

Tags: vmware-esxi

I am using VMWare ESXi 3.5 on my server, and I want to be able to remotely boot the server up. In the bios settings of the computer, I enabled Wake on Lan. I know usually with Windows XP and other Windows Operating Systems, you have to also enable wake on lan in the network card settings. Do I need to do this with ESXi, and if so, how?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at this KB http://kb.vmware.com/selfservice/microsites/search.do?language=en_US&cmd=displayKC&externalId=1003373

Answer (score 1):

You would need to add `ethernet0.wakeOnPcktRcv = "TRUE"` to each vmx file that you would like to enable WOL on.